# grabbing just required results from json --- restangular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, restangular

I am trying to grab just few ids from json and not the complete payload of json. Is that possible? here is my code

```
Car.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, CarRestangular) {


  $scope.cars = CarRestangular.all('car').getList();


});
```

here is my json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mike",

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Floyd",

    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Roy",

    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Roy",

    },

]
```

I want to get records where ids are 2 and 4. How could I do that. Also if possible, what would I need to do to get top two records in an other case that I would need.

Thanks

Comment: Use library like [lo-dash](http://lodash.com/docs), it has plenty on methods like [_.filter](http://lodash.com/docs#filter)

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of angular don't automatically unproxy promises in scope. Therefore you can't immediatelt do:

```
$scope.cars = CarRestangular.all('car').getList();
```

But you have to do:

```
CarRestangular.all('car').getList().then(function(result){
   $scope.cars = result;
));
```

The filtering would be the best if you have lodash included.

https://gist.github.com/lc-nyovchev/7414166e4dbf2dfbc908

You define a service with a method that does the filtering for you:

```
.factory('SomeService',['$q', 'Restangular', function($q,Restangular){

    return {
        someMethod: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            Restangular.all('car').getList().then(function(results){
            var filtered = _.filter(results, function(result){
                return result.id === 2 || result.id === 4;
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}])
```

Then you use the service in your controller:

```
.controller('YourController', ['SomeService', function(SomeService){
    SomeService.someMethod().then(function(filteredResult){
        $scope.cars = filteredResult;   
    });

}]);
```

Alternatively you can just do:

```
CarRestangular.all('car').getList().then(function(results){
   $scope.cars = _.filter(results, function(result){
      return result.id === 2 || result.id === 4;
   });
});
```

**Edit:** all those answers assume you want to do the filtering client side. IF your backend supports it, you can do something like:

```
CarRestangular.all('car').getList(id:[2,4]).then(function(result){
   $scope.cars = result;
));
```

And if your backend is written in such a way that is supports filtering on the id attribute, it would return you the correct results and you wouldn't have to filter them.